# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I am encountering a problem with html/javascript that I couldn't find a solution for on the web for the last ~7 hours eventhough similar questions were asked! All offered solutions that I tried didn't help me.

My problem is the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: *function* is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

[image]

I get this error when pressing a button that should trigger the function. The function is called onclick and the onclick attribute is attached to a div object.

```js
console.log("Main is alive");

function addArticletoSC() {
  console.log("Main is still alive!");
};
```

```html
<div class="article-element">
  <div class="picture_article-element">
    <img src="static/img/Chiquita_banana.PNG" alt="article" class="article_img">
  </div>
  <div class="text_article-element">
    <p class="name_info">Chiquita Banana
      <a href="/info" class="button button-small"><i class="material-icons button-color">info</i></a>
    </p>
    <div class="rating_comments">
      <a href="/comment_page" class="button button-small"><i class="material-icons rating">star_rate</i></a>
      <a href="/comment_page">4.5 / 5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="piece_price">
      <p>1 piece</p>
      <p class="price">0,50€</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="addtocart_article-element button" onclick="addArticletoSC()">
    <i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

If anybody could help me with that it would be very appreciated.

PS: This is my first HTML/CSS/JS project and I don't really know what I'm doing. Also, I am using **Framework7** for the project, idk if that is important.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. Works without error for me.

Comment: In the real code is `addArticletoSC()` defined at top-level? `onXXX` code runs in the global scope, it can't call nested functions.

Comment: Yes, addArticletoSC() is not nested in another function if you mean that. Actually, this is my whole main.js script right now.

Answer (score 0):

you may forgot script tag . try this anyway..

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<script>
    console.log("Main is alive");

    function addArticletoSC() {
        console.log("Main is still alive!");
    }
</script>
<div class="article-element">
    <div class="picture_article-element">
        <img src="static/img/Chiquita_banana.PNG" alt="article" class="article_img">
    </div>
    <div class="text_article-element">
        <p class="name_info">Chiquita Banana
            <a href="" class="button button-small"><i class="material-icons button-color">info</i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="rating_comments">
            <a href="" class="button button-small"><i class="material-icons rating">star_rate</i></a>
            <a href="">4.5 / 5</a>
        </div>
        <div class="piece_price">
            <p>1 piece</p>
            <p class="price">0,50€</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="addtocart_article-element button" onclick="addArticletoSC()">
        <i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
</html>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<script>
    console.log("Main is alive");

    function addArticletoSC() {
        console.log("Main is still alive!");
    }
</script>
<div class="article-element">
    <div class="picture_article-element">
        <img src="" alt="article" class="article_img">
    </div>
    <div class="text_article-element">
        <p class="name_info">Chiquita Banana
            <a href="" class="button button-small"><i class="material-icons button-color">info</i></a>
        </p>
        <div class="rating_comments">
            <a href="" class="button button-small"><i class="material-icons rating">star_rate</i></a>
            <a href="">4.5 / 5</a>
        </div>
        <div class="piece_price">
            <p>1 piece</p>
            <p class="price">0,50€</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="addtocart_article-element button" onclick="addArticletoSC()">
        <i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out but unfortunately it did not resolve my issue. Maybe framework 7 is my problem here?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this solved your problem, i changed the div tag into a clickable button tag so the 'onclick' function can execute....goodluck

```js
console.log("Main is alive");

function addArticletoSC() {
  console.log("Main is still alive!");
};
```

```html
<div class="article-element">
  <div class="picture_article-element">
    <img src="static/img/Chiquita_banana.PNG" alt="article" class="article_img">
  </div>
  <div class="text_article-element">
    <p class="name_info">Chiquita Banana
      <a href="/info" class="button button-small"><i class="material-icons button-color">info</i></a>
    </p>
    <div class="rating_comments">
      <a href="/comment_page" class="button button-small"><i class="material-icons rating">star_rate</i></a>
      <a href="/comment_page">4.5 / 5</a>
    </div>
    <div class="piece_price">
      <p>1 piece</p>
      <p class="price">0,50€</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <!-- replaced div tags with button tags -->
  
  <button class="addtocart_article-element button" onclick="addArticletoSC()">
    <i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i>
  </button>
  <br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the error says now that the function is not defined at HTML**Button**Element.onclick.